# Updating multiple machines to Yosemite

Tags: macos

We have about 10 Mac Minis in the office. All are running Mavericks. I want to update them all to Yosemite but each downloading the 5GB update seems a bit inefficient.

Is there any way to download Yosemite once and somehow get this onto each of the minis?

Answer (score 5):

On one machine download Yosemite from the AppStore.  When the Yosemite installer pops up you can quit that.  Go to **Applications-->Install OS X Yosemite.app** and copy the installer app. Then copy the installer to the other minis using your preferred local distribution method (ex. flash drive, ARD, cmd line).

Answer (score 0):

tron_jones has a great answer.
Additionally, if you'd like to make a USB key so that you can do more than just update a system in place, you can follow these instructions:
http://www.iclarified.com/44701/how-to-make-a-bootable-os-x-yosemite-usb-install-key

I use the install keys to do installs where I first want to wipe the harddrive clean. But they work just fine for updating as well.

Whichever option you choose - just make sure that you QUIT the installer right after it downloads from the apple store. If you let that install run - it will delete the files you need to do updates on other computers.

Comment: It is much easier and more reliable to just use DiskMakerX to make a USB stick, but yes, those instructions will work

Comment: I didn't know that existed! Thanks for the suggestion. DiskMakerX is available here - http://diskmakerx.com/